# Why do config files stored in Dropbox not work?

Tags: backup, autohotkey, dropbox, window, config-files

Recently I have moved an AutoHotKey script and an AntiMicro profile to a Dropbox folder to avoid suddenly losing them if something happens. Since then new problems arise:

- The AutoHotKey script cannot be read by Task Scheduler in every log on. It can't be simply put a shortcut in `shell:startup` because Windows doesn't provide highest privilege for it.
  [image]
- AntiMicro occasionally stops working and need me to manually refresh it.

Right-clicking the files does not show this message:

[image: image description]

I know that I can simply write an auto backup script and place them in a local folder, but why does this not work?

Comment: Downloaded files can have some extended file attributes set that denote them specifically as downloaded files. As such Windows can refuse to run them unless you clear those attributes first. I can't remember what they are specifically, will try to look later.

Comment: If you right-click the file and go to properties, do you see the following at the bottom? https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmkDN.png

Comment: @Mokubai no it's not